# How can I apply a function to a list using map?

Tags: perl, dictionary

I want to apply a function to every item of a list and store results similar to `map(function, list)` in python.

Tried to pass a function to map, but got this error:

```
perl -le 'my $s = sub {}; @r = map $s 0..9'
panic: ck_grep at -e line 1.
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a scalar variable holds a code reference -- for example:

```
my $double = sub { 2 * shift };
```

You can invoke the code very much the way you would in Python, like this:

```
$double->(50);  # Returns 100.
```

Applying that to a `map` example:

```
my @doubles = map $double->($_), 1..10;
```

Or this way:

```
my @doubles = map { $double->($_) } 1..10;
```

The second variant is more robust because the block defined by the `{}` braces can contain any number of Perl statements:

```
my @doubles = map {
    my $result = 2 * $_;

    # Other computations, if needed.

    $result;  # The return of each call to the map block.
} 1..10;
```

Comment: Nice answer, also note that in the map block, unlike most other blocks, you can _not_ install lexical pragmas or do other compile time actions (`use ...`/`no ...`).

Comment: You can use *use* and *no* in *map BLOCK LIST* forms of *map*, not in *map EXPR LIST* forms, it is just that if you use them you might need to disambiguate the block from an expression with a leading ;.  Alternatively you can use a *do BLOCK* as an expression, and that can contain *no* and *use*.  use strict; my @a = 1..10; my @b = map {; no strict 'vars'; $x = $_ + 1; $x } @a; my @c = map { do { no strict 'vars'; $x = $_+ 1; $x} } @a;

Comment: Also worth noting is that the *$_* in the loop is an alias for the array elements, so modifying it modifies the source array, which is not recommended for clear code.

Answer (score 5):

try : `map { $s->($_) } (0..9)` instead of `map $s 0..9`

explanation : in you example, `$s` is a reference to a subroutine, so you must dereference it to allow subroutin calling. This can be achieved in several ways : `$s->()` or `&$s()` (and probably some other ways that I'm forgetting)

Answer (score 5):

```
  my $squared = sub {
        my $arg = shift();
        return $arg ** 2;
  };
```

then either

```
   my @list = map { &$squared($_)  } 0 .. 12;
```

or

```
   my @list = map { $squared->($_) } 0 .. 12;
```

or maybe

```
my $squared;
BEGIN {
    *Squared = $squared = sub(_) {
        my $arg = shift();
        return $arg ** 2;
    };
}
my @list = map { Squared } 0 .. 12;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not too different from Python.

```
@results = map { function($_) } @list;
@results = map function($_), @list;
```

or with "lambdas",

```
@results = map { $function->($_) } @list;
@results = map $function->($_), @list;
```